# Android Emulator google maps showing wrong location

Tags: flutter, api, google-maps, maps, direction

My android emulator google map showing wrong location in usa but im in pakistan how do i change it to my current location

Comment: Due to software limitations and privacy concerns, I don't think emulators are capable of live location data.

Answer (score 8):

Open the emulator location settings by clicking on the three dots on the bottom right-hand side. It should be the very first page. Type in your address and confirm it by clicking the "Set Location" button.

[image]

Comment: thanks bro my issue resolved

Comment: Glad to help man.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set location as manually.
please follow this:

open emulator
select option
go to location
in map search bar you can type your address and set it
now refresh the app or map
done